# how to build a custom picker control

Tags: 2010, custom-form, people-picker

I wanted to build a picker control that would work upon a ECT like the out of the box picker but at the same time would also be able to show the picker dialogue based on some filtering criteria programmatically fed into it and the user will not be able to use the filters in the dialogue pop up.

till now the only blog that talks about building a custom picker is :
http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/index.php/2009/10/create-a-custom-picker-in-sharepoint-2010/

Could someone tell me how to achieve this? Hopefully without having to build a whole custom control for myself.

Thanks,
--OM

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [iLove Sharepoint Lookup Field with Picker 2010](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/44989)

I will say only this: I love it!

**EDITED:**

If you are looking for cascading scenario then take a look at [SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns).

> **Functionality**
>
> The SPCascadeDropdowns function lets you set up cascading dropdowns on
>   SharePoint forms. What this means is that you can enforce hierarchical
>   relationships between column values.

Creator of SPServices @MarcDAnderson is member here at SPSE.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm looking for something different. I need to build a cascading scenario where after choosing one picker entity it would show a second pop with data filter by the first option. Both the times it would be reading an external content type.

Comment: @OyshikMoitra - Since it was unclear to me that this is your ultimate goal I have updated my answer.